# TextWrapping on Windows Phone 7 Button

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am having a problem trying to get text to wrap on a windows phone button. The problem is that the text justs gets cut off! I have tried almost everything but the problem persists. I have searched the problem but I havent found a solution that has worked.

This is my code:

```
    <Button Height="127" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,548,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" Click="button1_Click" Foreground="#FFEBF362" FontFamily="Segoe WP" BorderBrush="#FFEDF0F1" Background="#FF1BA1E2" >
        <Button.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="Button" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="84"  TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" FontSize="36" Width="186" FontFamily="Segoe WP" />
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of setting the content like you have, you could use a ContentTemplate:

```
<Button Name="button1" Content="Hello Cakes">
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

This would then work if you wanted to set `button1.Content` from code. In addition, you could pull out the DataTemplate into a resource and reuse it between buttons.

This is also much better practice.

Comment: Hi Duncan, This is exactly what I was looking for thanks a million. The way I did it above did work but I could not center the text on the button properly and it just didn't look right. I have done as you suggested and it works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I tried the code and it seems to work, any chance you have the button nested in an element that has a constrained size? You've set some sizes as well, so there will be some limits to how much text you can see with the fontsize and font family. With the text 'Button Button Button Button' only the two first button will show, the second one on a new line, with the same font and fontsize (when I tried the code- I only changed one of the margins from 499 to 99 for the screen shot)

[image]

Maybe if you share some more code we can help you find the culprit, but check the sizes, margins, and elements. It is so easy to miss something!

Comment: Hi Iris, thank you very much for the response. I have tried as you suggested and reset the font to its default value, but the text is still not wrapping. The text on the button is changed dynamically in the c# code. I am using the windows phone 7 SDK if that makes any difference? I will edit the code above and add the rest of the xaml.

Comment: I just tried it as you have done above and the text does wrap! However when the String is set in c# button1.content = "Button Button"; I have the same issue again :(

Comment: Maybe if gave the textblock a name instead of calling button1.content that might work!

Comment: You need to set the text of the textblock , myTxtBlock.Text = "something something";in code with the name of the textblock set to myTxtBlck, since that is were you set the textwrapping attribute. Or even better use bindings, do you know what they are and how they work?

Comment: Yes that was my problem, I was setting button.content and not the textBlock.Text! I have not came across bindings before, I am fairly new to Windows Phone Dev but I will definitely look them up now. Thanks a million for the help I really appreciate it!